# Ho to create anchor link with github pages deployment?

Tags: github-pages

I have app running on github pages. Im trying to create and share anchor link

`http://myorg.github.io/app#sectionToNavigate`

For some reason github pages adds `/` after the hash and doest scroll properly to the anchor. As this mechanism seems to work on other deployements normally it seems to be something github pages specific. Do you known is it somehow avoidable?